# Update Wordpress Custom Field with AJAX on cached page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery, custom-fields

I'm new to ajax am trying to create a simple hit counter that updates a custom field in Wordpress after the page loads.  The page is cached, so any attempts to use PHP alone will not work.

I'd like to simply pass the post ID through ajax to the php file, get the custom field, and update it with the new hit number.

I currently have the following code, but cannot get it to update the custom field.  Here's the jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(
    $.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/hits/hits.php',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {PostId: '<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>'}
    });
));
```

And the PHP file it calls:

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: AJAX  */ 
?>

<?php 
    $postid = $_POST['PostId'];  // get the hits from AJAX and save it for PHP      

    $hits = (int) get_post_meta($postid, 'hit_number', true);
    $newhits = $hits + 1;
    update_post_meta($postid, 'hit_number', $newhits);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, is there a way to include the PHP function in the same page/file to avoid bringing in an external file?  I'm concerned that as traffic gets larger, the file will be requested too often.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamp in the query string.

```
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.getTime();

$(document).ready(function(
    $.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/hits/hits.php?t=' + timestamp,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {PostId: '<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>'}
    });
));
```

The purpose of adding timestamp in query string is a workaround to prevent getting cached results.

Comment: Timestamp?  What does the timestamp do?

Comment: I see.  Added that, but the script is still not updating the custom field.

Comment: I changed the data field from `status` to `PostId`. Does it work now?

Comment: That was actually a typing error in the question.  Both have PostId as the variable.  I corrected that and it should show on this page.

Comment: I revised my question. Does it update the custom field now? If not, try output the old hit value and new hit value in `hits.php` for some debugging.